# No permissions to save QTP's Object Repositories on shared network folders

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, qtp, network-share, shared-directory

Whenever I try to save Object Repositories on my company's shared network folders, QTP complains by saying:
"You do not have the required permission to save in this folder. Do you want to save the file in the My Documents folder instead?"
Thing is, I do have permission to read and write on the folder to which I am trying to save. Moreover, I don't have admin privileges, so running QTP as Admin isn't possible. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QTP is able to save to shared network folders AND it does have the permission to do it.

The trick is to use the full UNC path. This means that if you wanted to save the file `GlobalStore.tsr` inside of:

```
\\somewhere.corpnet.com\Groups\QA\Automation\Object Repository\
```

You would put in the 'File name' field the whole path:

```
\\somewhere.corpnet.com\Groups\QA\Automation\Object Repository\GlobalStore.tsr
```

[image: Save to the full UNC path in the File Name field]